# Dotnetnuke-Adding dnn module to dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have downloaded free dnn module of chat from following site: http://www.tmmworld.net/tabid/53/Default.aspx.

I have installed dotnetnuke properly but I am not getting how to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Login as admin or host.

Go to Admin | Extensions

Scroll all the way to the bottom of the page and click Install Extension Wizard. (or hover over the little triangle next to the Word Extensions to get a drop down menu)

Use the file chooser to select the .zip file for your chat module.

Follow the rest of the wizard steps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, ScottS stopped at the point of installing the module into the DNN Instance. Once that's done you have the module properly setup and ready to use in DotNetNuke, but you then need to add it to a page to have it show to users.

Once the module is installed, you then browse to the page that you want the functionality on, and then from the control panel at the top of the page, click to install the module on to the page (normally in the main/center Content Pane).

Answer (score 0):

go to host, extensions, then on manage click on install new extension then browse your zip file

Answer (score 0):

Login as Host.
Under Host -> Extensions -> press the button "Install Extension Wizard"

look at [DNN7 Example](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/542/view/details/how-to-install-a-module-in-dotnetnuke-7)